# php script longer on faster machine!

Tags: server, php

The problem is that webpage with many calculations on Ubuntu system (apache2 + php + mysql) loads considerably longer on faster pc. I have laptop with details:

```
Ubuntu 15.04 64bit
Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM Processor
6GB RAM
SSD disk
```

Script executes within ~13 seconds. However on server details:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1220 v2
16GB RAM and SSD (raid)
```

It takes ~47seconds. I ruled out mysql, because using EXPLAIN command I got practically same results. So i have no idea where to look further. What could be the problem for such different execution times?

Both computers are on different LANs and physically on different locations. Execution times are mesured on each computer locally.

Here are specs for both computers:

Laptop:

- Ubuntu 15.04 (64bit)
- Apache/2.4.10
- MySQL: Percona 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
- PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2

Server:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit)
- Apache/2.4.7
- MySQL: Percona 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11

PHP script: it consists of one `while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))` and inside goes calculations +, -, /, * of various numbers. Also bunch of `if`. It all gets stored in multilevel array. That's it.

Comment: Post software versions, and raid level on machine 2, otherwise this question is unanswerable. We might also need the php script too depending on the previous two.

Comment: We can't help without more detail. You would have to show us the script for one thing, or at least explain what it does. Where is the data coming from? Are they on the local machine (either the "server" or the laptop) or from somewhere else? Who is actually serving the webpage? One of the two machines you mention? A third? Are the server and laptop on the same network? Could one of them have a slower network connection?

Comment: I don't have direct access to server and i don't remember RAID level. I can remote ssh but i don't know command for finding out RAID level. I tried "cat /proc/mdstat" but it did not show any raid at all. Dev listing shows "/dev/mapper/isw_debjjejj_RAID0p2".

Comment: @terdon Both laptop and server are on different locations and different LANs. Script runs on both computers and the execution time difference is the problem. Network is not the problem, because i put markers to time the process and time shows local execution.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and clarify all this. Tell us that this is on different networks, tell us that you've checked that this is not the issue, tell us where the calculations are being performed. We don't have access to your set up and you need to give us enough information to be able to help. The obvious answer is that the laptop is using newer versions of the relevant software which, presumably, have been improved.